# Can we move a file from an FTP server to a local directory using apache camel endpoints?

Tags: apache, ftp, apache-camel, sftp, endpoint

I was wondering if it is possible to move or download a file from FTP server to a local directory using the apache camel endpoints properties?

I already searched this topic and couldn't find anything that could help me. Also, I'm not certain of its feasibility.

The endpoints URI=

> `sftp://user@ftp.com/outgoingFolder?password=*****&throwExceptionOnConnectFailed=true&maximumReconnectAttempts=0&stepwise=false&fastExistsCheck=true&disconnect=true&consumer.delay=300000&passiveMode=true`

I used "&move=C:\folder" as property but it didn't work and I get the following error

```
WARN - [SftpConsumer:213] Consumer Consumer[sftp://user@ftp.com/outgoingFolder?consumer.delay=300000&disconnect=true&fastExistsCheck=true&maximumReconnectAttempts=0&move=C%3A%5C%5Cfolders&passiveMode=true&password=xxxxxx&stepwise=false&throwExceptionOnConnectFailed=true] failed polling endpoint: Endpoint[sftp://user@ftp.com/outgoingFolder?consumer.delay=300000&disconnect=true&fastExistsCheck=true&maximumReconnectAttempts=0&move=C%3A%5C%5Cfolder&passiveMode=true&password=xxxxxx&stepwise=false&throwExceptionOnConnectFailed=true]. Will try again at next poll. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException - Cannot list directory:outgoingFolder]org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot list directory: outgoingFolder        at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations.listFiles(SftpOperations.java:617)        at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer.doPollDirectory(SftpConsumer.java:117)        at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer.pollDirectory(SftpConsumer.java:79)        at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:131)        at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:175)        at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:102)        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)Caused by: 4:        at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._stat(ChannelSftp.java:2208)        at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._stat(ChannelSftp.java:2215)        at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.ls(ChannelSftp.java:1565)        at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.ls(ChannelSftp.java:1526)        at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations.listFiles(SftpOperations.java:608)        ... 12 more Caused by: java.io.IOException: inputstream is losed        at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.fill(ChannelSftp.java:2884)        at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.header(ChannelSftp.java:2908)        at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._stat(ChannelSftp.java:2189)        ... 16 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, &move option is intended for moving file in scope of remote filesystem.

Use this instead:

```
from("sftp://user@ftp.com/outgoingFolder?password=*****&throwExceptionOnConnectFailed=true&maximumReconnectAttempts=0&stepwise=false&fastExistsCheck=true&disconnect=true&consumer.delay=300000&passiveMode=true")
.to("file:C:\\folder");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to download the file first to local directory and then move it.

```
from("sftp://userName@ftp.com/outgoingFolder?password=*****")
.to("file:D:\\folder");
```